# Change values in <td>'s with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of values. Is it possible with JQuery by clicking on currency link to change value in cells with exchange rates? This static example table

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td class="currency">100</td>
      <td class="currency">200</td>
      <td class="current">now in USD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="currency">150</td>
      <td class="currency">230</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="currency">400</td>
      <td class="currency">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="currency">550</td>
      <td class="currency">2920</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <a href="#" class="USD">USD</a>
  <a href="#" class="EUR">EUR</a>
```

Pls look [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/halofourteen/PjPYV/2/). In other words by clicking on currency values must recalculate them according to rates. In my example on jsfiddle I want to understand how simply change value(for example `usd=1` `eur=1.3`) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible, what have you tried?

Comment: Your fiddle does not have the JavaScript/JQuery. Show what you have tried.

Comment: @undefined I've tried with .val() but I think this is not thi right method in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to store the original USD values so you can use those as a base for all exchange rates. A `data-x` attribute is perfect for this.

```
$('.currency').each(function() {
    $(this).data('usd-value', $(this).text());
});
```

You can then simply multiply this value by whatever exchange rate you need, again stored in a `data` attribute on the link itself. Try this:

```
<a href="#" class="exchange USD" data-exchangerate="1">USD</a>
<a href="#" class="exchange EUR" data-exchangerate="1.3">EUR</a>
<a href="#" class="exchange GBP" data-exchangerate="0.63">GBP</a>
```

```js
$(".exchange").click(function() {
    var rate = $(this).data('exchangerate');
    $('.currency').each(function() {
        $(this).text(parseFloat($(this).data('usd-value') * rate));
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PjPYV/7/)

Note I also added `GBP` just to show how extensible this method is.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way too:-

```
var flag = false;
$('.USD').click(function() {
    if (flag)
    {
        $('.currency').each(function() {
            $(this).text(parseFloat($(this).text() / 1.3));
        });
        flag = false;
        $('.current').text("Now in USD");
        $('.EUR').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
$('.EUR').click(function() {
    flag = true;
    $('.currency').each(function() {
        $(this).text(parseFloat($(this).text() * 1.3));
    });
    $('.current').text("Now in EUR");
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/PjPYV/14/)**

Comment: Watch what happens when you repeatedly click an exchange link

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Yes, there is a bug. Now I have fixed.

Comment: Still happens when you keep clicking EUR. The logic is a little flawed to be honest as you are working with constantly changing numbers, rather than doing the calculation on the values as they were on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can select them by class and modify them:

```
$('.currency').each(function(){
    var eurMultiplier = 1.3;
    var currentValue = parseInt($(this).html());
    var newValue = currentValue * eurMultiplier;
    $(this).html(newValue);
});
```

this code is untested, but shoud give you a hint on how to do it.